# If $8$ does not divide $x^2-1$, then $x$ is even; prove by contrapositive

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $8$ does not divide $x^2-1$, then $x$ is even

proof by contrapositive

the contrapositive of this is :
if $x$ is odd, then $8$ divides $x^2-1$

proof by contrapositive:

Assume $x$ is odd

by definition of odd $∃k∈ℤ$ such that $x=2k+1$

Well, $x^2-1$ = $(2k+1)^2-1$

= $4k^2+4k$

= $4k(k+1)$

Therefore, $k(k+1)$ is an even integer

( i also know the definition of division : $∃m∈ℤ$ such that $x^2-1$ = $8m$)

$x^2-1$ = $4 · 2 · k(k+1)/2$

Therefore,

$8(k^2+1)/2$ is divisible by 8

Comment: No, you need to show that $k^2 + k$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: $k$ and $k^2$ have the same parity

Comment: The expression $k^2+k=k(k+1)$ is the product of two consecutive integers, and exactly one of those is even.

Comment: $k^2+k=k(k+1)$$

Comment: okay i get it now, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 does not divide $x^2-1$ is the same as

"if 8 divides $x^2-1$, then x is odd"

which is the same as:
$$8|(x^2-1)\rightarrow 2|(x+1)$$
but
$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$
Then since $8=4*2$

Two divides both $x-1$ and $x+1$, and we proven our case

Comment: This is a direct argument rather than a use of the contrapositive. Very neat and tidy, though.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $$(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$$ If 8 does not divide $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$, then 2 does not devide $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$. But that is the same as saying that neither $x-1$ nor $x+1$ are even. Hence $x$ must be even.